# .change() function on dom element generated after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i'm trying to catch a change() on a select which is added after the dom generation but i can't success. Here is a sample code:

HTML:

```
<div class="test" id="divTest"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#divTest').click(function(){ $(this).parent().append("<select id='testSel'><option value='f'>F</option><option value='F'>D</option></select>");});

$('#testSel').change(function(){
    alert('change');
});
```

I want to see the alert when i change the value in the select..

And here is a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/T8J8p/3/

Comment: Use delegation instead.

Comment: 1. Since you're manipulating the DOM, you should use `on`.
2. It's a bad thing to have more than one element with the same ID. (If the user would click the button more than once...)
3. Your current `select` element has `id='testS'` while in your bind event you're writing `#testSel`.

Comment: Every one heard about Jquery `live` event.

Comment: @JitendraYadav jQuery's `live` event was deprecated in jQuery 1.7. `on` should be used instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Your `select` element's ID is `#testS` not `#testSel`.<sup>1</sup>
2. You need to use [*event delegation*](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for this, through jQuery's `on()` method:

```js
$('body').on('change', '#testS', function(){
    alert('change');
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8J8p/1/).

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

---

<sup>1. This related to original JSFiddle featured in the question (available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T8J8p/)). The question has since been edited.</sup>

Comment: how to make grey background around text @James?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, that grey background denotes that that text is a blockquote and can be achieved by prefixing your text with a `>` (e.g. `> Text here...`).

Comment: @EhsanSajjad you can also use the edit function just for see how the text is formatted...

Comment: @JamesDonnelly yes, sorry i forgot to mention that i edited the original question & the fiddle to remove the typo.

Comment: @Superdrac no worries; I figured I'd just add the clarification in my answer to not confuse any future visitor. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) dynamically added DOM::

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on('change','#testS',function(){
 alert('change');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VELNk/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('body').on("change", "#testSel", function(){
    alert('change');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind event  using [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as the element is added to the DOM after the DOM loaded:

```
$(document).on('change','#testSel',function(){
    alert('change');
});
```

See [**Details HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#divTest').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().append("<select id='testS'><option value='f'>F</option><option value='F'>D</option></select>");
  $('#testS').change(function(){alert('change');});
});
```

You can't bid to something that does not exist yet, so bind it after the click, inside the function.
And there was a typo in the selector #testS vs #testSel